# Gravitational field as protection for tanks or battleships

Tags: warfare, gravity

Could a tank or battleship create a gravitational field around itself to stop incoming bullets and to crush them, just with high gravity?

The field would be thin and not directly on the tank.
So if a bullet went in to the gravitational field, to escape it, it would a lot of energy witch it probably wouldn’t have after entering the gravitational field.
Also this is a scenario in the future.

Comment: Every object projects a gravitational field. Most objects on scales managable by human beings project such tiny gravitational fields that they are completely overpowered by the celestial body they are on. (For example, a tank on Earth.) Newton's theory of gravity is generally sufficient: $F = G\frac{m_1m_2}{r^2}$ for masses $m_1$ and $m_2$, distance $r$ and a constant $G$ (the gravitational constant); in everyday situations, we don't need general relativity's gravitational model. See [Newton's theory of gravitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity#Newton.27s_theory_of_gravitation).

Comment: Gravity is an attractive force, not a repulsive one (unless negative mass is involved, but that's another story). You are suggesting using gravity for point defense? The only way to do that would be to fold space around the tank so that incoming bullets always miss. In which case, the tank is generating a singularity anyway.

Comment: If you have this sort of tech and your enemy is using bullets you can't help but winning. I don't mean this particular use, I mean that you could do far more destructive things with similar tech, ike firing black holes at them.

Comment: I feel like everyone is misunderstanding gravitational fields for some reason. Was a movie or something involving them pushed out recently?

Answer (score 7):

So, first of all, I want to make sure everyone knows that we can't actually create artificial gravity fields.

But even if we could, I think it's important to note that pretty much any technology can be used in a variety of ways. Consider what kind of gravity it would take to, say, divert a bullet. Bullets can travel hundreds or even thousands of meters before gravity pulls them into the ground, and that's using all the gravity generated by the entire Earth. So what you're proposing would have to create a gravitational force equivalent to a body many times larger than the Earth, supposedly generated and contained around a normal-sized tank. There are a few problems with this:

1- The tank will get squished.
2- Anyone inside or nearby the tank will get squished. 
3- Anyone shooting the tank from above (or in the direction of the gravitational forces) will have their projectiles super-accelerated.

3 has a corollary problem that I alluded to earlier: if you're capable of generating as much acceleration as you're asking for, you can turn it towards the enemy and use it as a weapon. What you're describing is a lot like trying to stop a bullet by shooting at it; maybe with a powerful enough gun you could manage it, but you'll probably have much better luck shooting the shooter. Especially considering that bullets accelerated by this gravity technology might even be powerful enough to penetrate the gravity shields.

It's also worth considering how much power this would consume. Like I said, the technology doesn't exist yet, but I think we can assume it's going to require a constant source of a *lot* of electricity. Considering tanks already have problems staying supplied with gasoline, unless they've got a portable fusion reactor on board I don't think they're going to be able to generate this field for too long. And if you have a fusion reactor in all of your tanks, it's going to be a really bad idea to leave them unprotected for too long.

Long story short, rather than using this magical gravity field to block projectiles, it's probably safer and more effective to use it to make railguns, or antigravity planes with railguns.

Comment: Very good answer. On the matter of power supply though, my guess is we will have portable fusion reactor way before we can generate gravity fields (Cf. your first line) ^^

Comment: The Tank isn't the centre of the gravitational field, a layer around the tank would be the centre. Also power isn't an issue. But the idea with gravitational guns is very interesting, but how would you accelerated bullets with gravity.

Comment: @Jerry you're already planning on accelerating bullets using gravity, you're just assuming those bullets are being fired at the tank first. Apply a similar acceleration to a stationary bullet and you should be able to send it flying at bullet speeds in some direction away from the tank. Make sure that direction is towards the enemy and you have your gravity gun.

Comment: @Jerry - how can a layer around the tank be the center of anything? You can't _project_ gravity like some kind of light show - gravity, by definition, pulls objects towards the source. If the tank generated gravity, projectiles would be pulled in _towards_ the tank. Similarly, if you had a gravity generator between the tank and the shooter, the tank, as well as the projectile, would get pulled in towards the generator.

Comment: +1 for a solid answer and I would add an  additional +1 for railguns because railguns are awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it depends on just how hard you want to wave your hands.

Let's say that you have Whizzo Gravity Inverter (TM) which takes a volume of space and inverts the direction of gravity within it. Lets' say that the volume (your shell) is one meter thick. A deceleration of 1 g over 1 meter simply is not going to make an appreciable difference in the speed of an APDS (Armor Piercing Discarding Sabot) anti-tank round.

So, in addition to turning space inside out, you want to crank up the volume. You want to stop a projectile going about 5000 fps in 1 meter due to gravitational forces. Then it will "fall" back toward the source, regaining its speed as it does, sort of like throwing a ball straight up and having it fall back down. Well, you might want to rethink this one. Consider what happens to air molecules inside the shell - as they enter the shield they will be powerfully pushed outwards by the gravitational forces and all the air will be sucked out of the field. You also might think about the interaction of the shield with the dirt where the shield contacts the earth.

You mean the shield is not a sphere? Oh, come on now. Making spherical fields is the norm in nature - gravitational, electric, magnetic, etc. Sure you can tailor such shapes, but for gravity?

Like I say, the amount of handwaving required, at least based on current knowledge, gets pretty outrageous. I'd recommend that you just mention the effects, and maybe a throwaway line about "distorting space". Your shield, at present, is a good example of Arthur C. Clarke's epigram: "Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic." Don't bother yourself with trying for a credible explanation - it's magic.

Answer (score 1):

Gravity is an attractive force.  It cannot "push" anything "down." It always "pulls" things "in."  The only reason we feel as though gravity is a downward force is because we are being pulled to the center of the Earth which is so far down below us that the force feels flat to us (unless we get sensitive instruments, or are flying fast like satellites).  If the tank, itself, was generating this field, it would actually pull the bullet towards it, not away.

To have gravity work this way, the "source" of the gravitational pull would need to be very far below ground.  It would need to be very powerful (hundreds if not thousands of gee's) and directional to avoid pulling everything into it, including the tank itself.  A key detail: I am not aware of anything to shape gravitational fields besides the distortion of spacetime.  The peculiar shapes needed to have this effect may actually be impossible, but I'm not a General Relativity theorist, so they may have some tricks.  However, even if one does this, one still has to worry about crushing the rock below the tank with thousands of gee's, causing earthquakes that could be more dangerous than the bullet.

You might be able to word something interesting involving gravity waves, if you could generate a bunch of them at different frequencies, you could create regions with astonishing gravitational gradients by lining the different signals up at that point.  However, that's pure speculation, and the tremendous gravities required to make gravity waves of any reasonable size appear may cause even more earthquakes!

My advice would be to use a magnetic force instead.  Magnetic forces interact with a body at right angles to both the magnetic field and the velocity of the object.  This means if you could somehow construct a magnetic field which has field lines going left-to-right, incoming rounds would be turned downward.

Comment: I meant, it would create a layer with such a high pressure, that everything would be pressed together and would lose its speed, because the field is the point where the bullet would be pulled to.

Comment: Unfortunately, unless you use exotic (and *extremely* weak) gravity waves, there's no way to make gravity not behave like an attractive force towards the center of a mass.  Thus, the only way to create that high density layer via gravity would be to put a large mass at the bottom of that desired gravity well.  A few black holes the mass of Jupiter should be sufficient for your battleship.  Unfortunately, once you do that, gravity behaves like gravity, and your defense system will suck the entire planet into it, including the battleship.

Comment: Gravity waves would be fun, but a) I'm not 100% sure if even they can do this, although there *should* be some wave effect similar to hull speed you can leverage.  and b) It may require more mass than you have in the entire galaxy to generate meaningful gravity waves on that power scale.

Answer (score 0):

You realize gravity is a force of "Attraction" of masses. If a high gravitational field exists or is emitted by an object, say...a tank, then a projectile fired in it's direction will INCREASE in velocity the closer it gets.